# Quick question on natural log

Tags: logarithms

I was reading my math book and got confused by this

> $$\ln \left(\sqrt 2 -1\right)=\ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 +1}\right) =-\ln \left(\sqrt 2 +1\right)$$

How do they get this equality in the hyperlink above? I don't know how to find this except by plugging in both sides into a calculator. Is there an algebraic way of achieving this?

Comment: Mul. and div by $1+\sqrt2$. So, the numerator becomes $(\sqrt2-1)(\sqrt2+1) = 2-1$

Comment: An illuminating exercise here is to multiply out $(\sqrt2-1)(\sqrt2+1)$ and then divide the end-result by either of those original brackets.

Comment: @Ak19 Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$\sqrt 2 -1=(\sqrt 2 -1)\cdot \frac{\sqrt 2 +1}{\sqrt 2 +1}= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 +1}$$

then we simply use that

$$\ln \left(\frac 1 A\right) =\ln \left(A^{-1}\right)= -\ln A$$

Comment: Thanks for the help.